# cancancan custom action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1, cancancan

Am using cancancan and activeadmin gems in my application, in cancan gem the custom action is not working.

ability.rb

```
 if ((user.has_role? :HRMS_Supervisor) && (user.has_application? :HRMS))
       can :manage, User
       can :approve, User  // custom action
    end

    if ((user.has_role? :HRMS_Employee) && (user.has_application? :HRMS))
      can :read,   Employee
      can :manage, User
      can :employee_access, User // custom action
    end
```

my activeadmin file

```
ActiveAdmin.register Teleworker do
  scope :pending,  default: true
  scope :approved
  scope :rejected, if: proc{ can? :employee_access, current_user }
  scope :all

 index  do
  selectable_column
  column "Action" do |resource|
    links = ''.html_safe
    if can? :approve, current_user
     links += link_to "approve", resource_path(resource), class: "member_link view_link"
    end
  end
end
```

the rejected  scope and link_to "approve" is displaying for both the roles. how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`can :manage, User` already includes all custom actions. So, both your roles can perform both custom actions.

You can use the list of crud actions: `can %i(create read update delete), User` instead `can :manage, User` for both roles.

Comment: ...and also you need to authorize your custom action: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions

Comment: link broken, refer to [the developer documents](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/README.md)